# Documentclass for hybrid of presentation and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

i am looking for a solution to build a onepager in DinA3 for 2 flows.
How you can see I need a picture and table in one figure and only a table in the next one. Also an arrow is important (this is an example) .

Does anyone know a solution? I am thinking of the documentclass beamer to define the pagesize and tikz to draw maybe the arrows.

[image]

Comment: Beamer is made for virtual presentations, so why would you use it for a A3 paper?

Comment: Hi, I want to print a big onepager wirh qr codes for a barcode scanner. I need here some steps bevause the user need to scan 4 barcodes from 4 groups inna defined way

Comment: At best you can `\input` one TeX file with two different preambles, possibly creating a `\newif` to handle any format specific changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `beamerposter` package to change to a din A3 layout:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a3]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10,transform shape]
    \node[fill=blue,font=\color{white}] at (0,0) {Test};
    \draw[blue,-latex,line width=1cm] (0,-0.5) -- (-1,-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```